# how to hide last two dots value in IP Address in String using regex ?

Tags: regex

Example 
testdata10.21.21.32fsd10.210.21.1 
Result 
testdata10.21.XX.XXfsd10.210.XX.XX

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: Please have a look at the FAQ where it describes how to ask questions.

Comment: complete clear ,short way asked question and "WITH EXAMPLE"

Comment: I don't see any code.

Comment: see below comments for code

Comment: is there an example of what you have started for code or where you are getting hung up? :)

Comment: currently i am using this  (?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|‌​2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-‌​9][0-9]?) REGEX

Comment: but this is selecting Whole IP address but i want select last two dots

Answer (score 2):

You can use `re.sub(r'(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}', r'\g<1>.\g<2>.XX.XX', yourstring)` for example:

```
a = 'testdata10.21.21.32fsd10.210.21.1'
print re.sub(r'(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}', r'\g<1>.\g<2>.XX.XX', a)
```

will output:

```
'testdata10.21.XX.XXfsd10.210.XX.XX'
```

Comment: if i have this regex  and i want select last dot value than (?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)

Comment: if you want to select last dot value then you can change to `r'\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.(\d{1,3})'`

Answer (score 0):

maskedString.replaceAll("(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})", "XX.XX.$3.$4");